# PIL Image fails to plot the blank image from ndarray

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create a blank image and first try converting a ndarray to PIL Image, however,  generating the wrong image. Why does this strange thing happen?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

x = np.ones((256, 256)).astype(bool)

img = Image.new('1', (256, 256), 1)
y = np.asarray(img)

print((x == y).all())
# x equals to y, but ploting different pictures, why?

img1 = Image.fromarray(x, mode='1')
img1.show()

img2 = Image.fromarray(y, mode='1')
img2.show()
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `mode` to 8 bit pixels not only in `Image.new` but also in `Image.fromarray`:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

x = np.ones((256, 256)).astype(bool)

img = Image.new('L', (256, 256), 1)
y = np.asarray(img)

img1 = Image.fromarray(x, mode='L')
img1.show()

img2 = Image.fromarray(y, mode='L')
img2.show()
```